# What does the type `rune_t` represent in C?

Tags: c, types, freebsd

While browsing my GCC header `stddef.h`, I came across a type I never heard of, `rune_t`:

```
#if defined (__FreeBSD__) && (__FreeBSD__ >= 5)
#if !defined (_ANSI_SOURCE) && !defined (_POSIX_SOURCE)
#if __BSD_VISIBLE
#ifndef _RUNE_T_DECLARED
typedef __rune_t        rune_t;     /* <--- Here it is */
#define _RUNE_T_DECLARED
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

As per the surrounding `#if`s, I guess it is a FreeBSD-specific type, but what does it represent?

Bonus question: does it have anything to do with the [runic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes)?

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rune&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+5.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> man rune
>
> The 4.4BSD `rune` functions have been deprecated  in favour of the ISO C99 extended multibyte and wide character facilities and should not be used in new applications. Consider using setlocale(3), mbrtowc(3), wcrtomb(3), fgetwc(3), ungetwc(3),   and fputwc(3) instead.

It used to be something that deals with extended character sets. Exotic characters are sometimes called "runes" jokingly, hence the name. This type may or may not support the actual runic alphabet.

Comment: Ah! So that's how Go's wide character type got its name `rune`.